Regular exhaustion of a bounded domain $\Omega$ with smooth boundary.
A bounded domain $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary (Here smooth means $\partial\Omega$ is a (n-1) dimensional manifold) is said to have regular exhaustion iff
1)There exists a sequence of sub-domain $\{\Omega_n\}\subseteq\Omega$ such that $Cl(\Omega_n)\subseteq\Omega_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $\cup \Omega_n=\Omega$. This $\partial\Omega_{n}$ is smooth for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Now the question is that does any bounded open set $\Omega$ with smooth boundary have that regular exhaustion property? I can intuitively think about an answer but could not come with exact construction.
One standard construction using finitely many ball of $1/n$ radius covering $\partial\Omega$ is there but there smoothness might be an issue because the exhausting sequence might have boundaries with finitely many spikes or non differentiable point. Can anyone put any insight on it.
